# Как реализовать открытие/скрытие элемента?

Tags: activity, android, java

Есть элемент tableRow1. Изначально он должен быть скрытым. Потом с помощью java кода надо его открыть. Потом снова открыть. Как это всё сделать?

p.s. Вот какого эффекта я хочу добиться (до/после клика):
[image][image]

Comment: view.setVisibility(View.GONE)

Comment: Макс Ровкин, а с анимацией?

Comment: @Gorets, сделать анимацию для view и подписаться на ее прослушивание, когда анимация закончится, то сделать setVisibility(View.GONE), в обратной последовательности сделать появление. Остается понять, какую анимацию захочет топикстартер